# Order theory between radicals

Tags: order-theory, radicals

Consider $p$ and $q$ $∈$ **$N$** where $p>q$. What is the order between the numbers $\sqrt{2pq}$ and $\sqrt{p}+\sqrt{q}$?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  It depends on $p,q$.  For most choices $\sqrt {2pq}$ is bigger, but not for all choices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't clear what you are asking.

Might be worth remarking that, if $q≥2$ then:  $$\sqrt {2pq}\;≥\;2\sqrt p\;>\,\sqrt p+\sqrt q$$  so the only counterexamples might occur with $q=1$.

Indeed, if $q=1$ then we can have $\sqrt {2p}<\sqrt p+1$.  A little algebra shows that this works for $p\in \{1,2,3,4,5\}$.  So, other than those $5$ counterexamples, $\sqrt {2pq}$ is always bigger than $\sqrt p+\sqrt q$.